# Запрос на SQL из двух разных таблиц с условием и сортировкой

Tags: mysql, sql

````
Схема БД 01
таблица анализов Analysis:
 • an_id — ID анализа;
 • an_name — название анализа;
 • an_price — розничная цена анализа;
 • an_group — ID группы.
таблица групп анализов Groups:

 • gr_id — ID группы;
 • gr_name — название группы;
 • gr_temp — температурный режим хранения.
таблица заказов анализов Orders:

 • ord_id — ID заказа;
•  ord_num — Номер заказа;
 • ord_datetime — дата и время заказа;
 • ord_an — ID анализа. ```

 Как вывести все номера заказов и их стоимость. 
Условие: заказы оформлены с 01.01.2021 по 10.01.2021, 
в них есть анализы с ценой более 500 и менее 1000, 
сортировка по номеру заказа.?
````

Comment: видимо, как задание получили, так и отправили. чтоб уж совсем не напрягаться?

Comment: чтоб понятней было и вопросов лишних не было

Comment: так тут задания ни за кого не делают, вы свои попытки покажите и скажите что конкретно не получилось

Comment: @geu Ну нам всё понятно, и у нас вопросов лишних нет - делайте)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select al.an_id,al.an_price from analysis al
 inner join orders on orders.ord_an=al.an_id
 and orders.ord_datetime between '01.01.2021' and '10.01.2021'
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]